# To re-open antivirals/postherpetic pain question

Tags: support

Can someone help to re-open the question about [famciclovir and postherpetic pain](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/15946/continuing-effectiveness-of-anti-viral-drugs-after-shingles-outbreak)? I edited the question to be non-personal.

Comment: Sorry. Just a tip for your input: [What sort of nutrition or environmental questions are suitable now?](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/what-sort-of-nutrition-or-environmental-questions-are-suitable-now).